# How to create bundle files using "hg bundle" with every bundle-file size not exceeding say 1GB

Tags: version-control, mercurial, repository, bundle, distributed

I have a huge mercurial repository which is around 12GB.
I need to clone it in another machine but pulling it from the network takes lot of hours.
When I try to bundle all the changesets in to one bundle file the size of file is creating problems for the work environment I am working on.

I was wondering if there is a way to create small bundles seperately and then unbundle them in another machine?

Answer (score 3):

`hg help bundle` tells you that you can specify the changesets to include in a bundle as well as a base revision to consider. Combining these two, you can create a set of smaller bundles from your repository, up to the extend to exporting each revision as a separate bundle with the preceeding one indicated as the base rev considered already present:

```
 -r --rev REV [+]       a changeset intended to be added to the destination
 -b --branch BRANCH [+] a specific branch you would like to bundle
    --base REV [+]      a base changeset assumed to be available at the
                        destination
 -a --all               bundle all changesets in the repository
 -t --type TYPE         bundle compression type to use (default: bzip2)
```